# Plot surface from irregular data

Tags: matlab, visualization, data-visualization, matlab-figure, surf

I'm make a filled contour or surface plot from a scattered dataset.

A major difference from other Qs is that the data are not convex.

```
[r,th] = meshgrid(10:15,0:180);
[x,y] = deal(r.*sind(th), r.*cosd(th));
z = x.^2+y.^2;
scatter(x(:),y(:),[],z(:),'fill'); axis equal off;
```

The inner circle is null.

[image]

I use

```
tri = delaunay(x,y);
trisurf(tri,x,y,z);  view(2); axis equal off;
```

to make a surface plot.

However, as you can see, the inner circle is filled.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than using the Delaunay triangulation which results in the convex hull, you're going to want to use an [`alphaShape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/alphashape.html) with which you can impose a limit on the length of the resulting surfaces edges.

You can specify the [`Alpha` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/alphashape.html#inputarg_a) (by specifying a third input) which is the inverse of the maximum edge length. For your example, I've chosen an `Alpha` of  1.

```
A = alphaShape(x(:), y(:), 1);
```

You can then get the triangulation out using the [`alphaTriangulation`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/alphashape.alphatriangulation.html) method of your `alphaSurface` object.

```
[faces, vertices] = A.alphaTriangulation();
zvalue = sum(vertices.^2, 2);
```

Or you can use the `plot` method of the `alphaShape` object

```
plot(A, 'FaceColor', 'interp', 'CData', zvalue)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the complementary `alphaTriangulation`. Works perfect.